# how to call a function with a struct as a parameter in c

Tags: c, struct

I have a function that handles events from a touch display. The events are wrapped in a `struct`:

```
struct genieReplyStruct
{
  int cmd ;
  int object ;
  int index ;
  unsigned int data ;
} ;

void handleGenieEvent (struct genieReplyStruct *reply)
{
  if (reply->cmd != GENIE_REPORT_EVENT)
  {
    printf ("Invalid event from the display: 0x%02X\r\n", reply->cmd) ;
    return ;
  }

  /**/ if (reply->object == GENIE_OBJ_KEYBOARD)
  {
    if (reply->index == 0)  // Only one keyboard
      calculatorKey (reply->data) ;
    else
      printf ("Unknown keyboard: %d\n", reply->index) ;
  }
  else if (reply->object == GENIE_OBJ_WINBUTTON)
  {
    /**/ if (reply->index == 1) // Clock button on main display
      genieWriteObj (GENIE_OBJ_FORM, 1, 0) ;
    else if (reply->index == 0) // Calculator button on clock display
    {
      genieWriteObj (GENIE_OBJ_FORM, 0, 0) ;
      updateDisplay () ;
    }
    else
      printf ("Unknown button: %d\n", reply->index) ;
  }
  else
    printf ("Unhandled Event: object: %2d, index: %d data: %d [%02X %02X %04X]\r\n",
      reply->object, reply->index, reply->data, reply->object, reply->index, reply->data) ;
}
```

Now I want to simulate calling this `handleGenieEvent` function, but I am not sure how: I tried printing out the `struct` as an `int` and then call it but didn"t work. I also tried calling it with an array:

```
 void handleGenieEvent (-1090701828);
void handleGenieEvent ([21 0A 0000]);
```

Comment: What is printing the struct as `int`? What are these `void handleGenieEvent (-1090701828); void handleGenieEvent ([21 0A 0000]);`?

Comment: oh yeah forgot to mention that. `-1090701828` is what I get when I do printf("%d", reply) and `[21 0A 0000]` is printf ("[%02X %02X %04X]\r\n",
      reply->object, reply->index, reply->data)`

Comment: Oh boy, you need some basic C knowledge...

Comment: Why do you insert empty `/**/ ` comments before some of the `if` statements?

Comment: It's a code snippet from a github project

Comment: `reply` is a pointer. It is not called "struct" for the same reason an apple is not called "banana".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using C99 you could use Compound Literals:

```
handleGenieEvent(&(struct genieReplyStruct){GENIE_REPORT_EVENT, 0, 0, 0});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using C99 or later, use *Compound literals*, detailed in C11 6.5.2.5

```
handleGenieEvent(&(struct genieReplyStruct) { 0,1,2,3});
```

Or to simulate per OP's `[21 0A 0000]`

```
handleGenieEvent(&(struct genieReplyStruct) { cmd, 0x21, 0x0A, 0x0000});
```